# Для каждого потока собственное подключение к базе данных. Есть ли смысл?

Tags: python, потоки-данных, многопоточность, mysql

Добрый день. Допустим, запускается 20 потоков через Threading. Нужно вносить данные в БД. Вопрос: имеет ли смысл создавать db connect для каждого потока, увеличится ли скорость записи при таком раскладе, Или использовать одно подключение на каждый поток? Или на каждый поток нужно создавать свой cursor?

Подключение к БД

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host='10.10.10.10',user='art',passwd='123',db='parserinet')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8')
```

Comment: Не знаю как в MySQL, а в PostgreSQL в рамках одного коннекта может выполняться только одна транзакция, поэтому я просто создавал пул потоков (на каждый поток по коннекту).

Comment: Спасибо. Думаю такой комент сгодился бы в ответах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно обязательно создавать новое соединение, либо использовать пул соединений. Одновременное использование одного соединение в разных потоках может привести к весьма неприятным проблемам.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае стоит создать пул разумного количества соединений (может быть ограничение по количеству коннектов к БД, т.е., для MySQL, например, задана переменная  max_user_connections).

В общем случае выбор варианта может зависеть еще и от того, что вы делаете после.
Скажем, если вы выбираете какие-то данные из БД и потом много всего с ними делаете в разных потоках, можно и одним общим соединением обойтись: пока в одних потоках обработка, другие запрашивают нужные им данные из базы.